# Проблема с git clone (username and password)

Tags: git, github, git-clone

Проблема заключается в том, что у меня есть на github репозиторий и я от туда не могу вытащить проект, я использую git clone ... и у меня он запрашивает Username and Password. Я вводил username от аккаунта github и password от аккаунта github(ник и пароль верные, но пишет что не верно). Что не так?[image: Terminal Mac OS X]

Comment: VladiTek или VladiTeek? Это два разных пользователя, определитесь.

Comment: @andreymal я пробовал и тот и тот

Comment: Вы уверены, что не забыли исправить адрес репозитория?

Answer (score 0):

В итоге сделал подключение через SSH